# Conditional replacement of character in filename

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to rename:
`01.black_cat.mp3` to `01_black_cat.mp3`

But when I run:

```
rename -n 'y/^[0-9][0-9][.]*/^[0-9][0-9][_]*.mp3/' *.mp3
```

I get:

```
01.black_cat.mp3, 01_black_cat_mp3
```

I want to replace the first period but ignore the second one. What am I doing wrong?  Can this be done easier with MMV?  All of the examples I find are pattern matching for the end of the file or all instances within the filename.

Comment: Do you understand what `y` does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why you are using `y///` instead of `s///`.
Also,
you need to escape `.` in the pattern,
and the expression can be written simpler:

```
rename -n 's/^([0-9][0-9])\./$1_/' *mp3
```

This means, replace the starting two digits followed by a dot with the digits followed by underscore. The `$1` in the replacement expression means the matched string within `(...)` in the pattern.

Comment: This worked perfectly, although I feel really stupid because I do not know why it works.

Answer (score 1):

In straight Bash:

```
for fname in *.mp3; do mv "$fname" "${fname/./_}"; done
```

This loops over all `.mp3` files and uses [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to replace the first period with an underscore.

Answer (score 0):

rename is [not POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/utilities.html), you may prefer to use something like this:

```
printf '%s\n' *.mp3 | sed 'p;s/\./_/' |
while
  read pa
  read qu
do
  mv "$pa" "$qu"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as a note, the `y///` operator is the same as [tr///](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) which is transliterates the first list into the second.

Examples:

```
$ echo 'abcdefg' | perl -ple 'y/a-d/A-D/' 
ABCDefg
$ echo '12345' | perl -ple 'y/1-3/x-z/' 
xyz45
```

If you did not know, `rename` is based on Perl, so you can test what it will do as I am doing here.

This is what you are probably trying to do:

```
$ echo '01.black_cat.mp3' | perl -ple 's/^(\d+)\./\1_/'
01_black_cat.mp3
```